# Conditional Validation in Yup Formik React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik, yup

I am trying to add conditional validations for a field that exists is a part of one form but is not for the other.

This is my custom validation of yup.

```js
export const validationSchema = Yup.object({
  id: Yup.string(),
  name: Yup.string().required('required'),
  level: Yup.object().when('$exist', {
    is: (exist) => exist,
    then: Yup.object().typeError('required').required('required'),
    otherwise: Yup.object(),
  }),
});
```

In the case where the field is not present it is working fine as it should be. But the validation doesn't work when the field actually exists in the Formik form it returns with an error

> level must be a object type, but the field value was null. If "null" is intended as an empty value be sure to mark the schema as nullable()"

I want to make my "level" validation work for one case and not for the other

Comment: is `$exist` a form field?

Comment: All of the fields are common the only unique field is stage.

Comment: @Rookie, what is that `$exist`. And how to pass them like that?